# Is autorelease required in a @autoreleasepool if ARC is disabled?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In a `@autoreleasepool` block, I don't think you need (or even are permitted) to specify `autorelease` when under ARC. However, I'm not using ARC. Is the `autorelease` specifier needed in the code example below? It compiles without error/warning with or without it.

```
void some_function (const char *title) {
    @autoreleasepool{
        [_window setTitle:
            [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:title] autorelease]]; }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, otherwise the temporary string object leaks.

The fact that you can omit it in ARC is what makes "Automatic Retain Count" automatic.